# Change label when checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery, html, css, checkbox, label

I have a lot of listst with checkboxes like so:

```
<ul>
   <li><label class="highlight"><input type="checkbox" id="1" class="filteritem">Lorem Ipsum</label</li>
   <li><label class="highlight"><input type="checkbox" id="223" class="filteritem">Lorem Ipsum</label</li>
   <li><label class="highlight"><input type="checkbox" id="32" class="filteritem">Lorem Ipsum</label</li>
   <li><label class="highlight"><input type="checkbox" id="42" class="filteritem">Lorem Ipsum</label</li>
   <li><label class="highlight"><input type="checkbox" id="54" class="filteritem">Lorem Ipsum</label</li>
</ul>

<ul>
   <li><label class="highlight"><input type="checkbox" id="43" class="filteritem">Lorem Ipsum</label</li>
   <li><label class="highlight"><input type="checkbox" id="343" class="filteritem">Lorem Ipsum</label</li>
   <li><label class="highlight"><input type="checkbox" id="342" class="filteritem">Lorem Ipsum</label</li>
   <li><label class="highlight"><input type="checkbox" id="53" class="filteritem">Lorem Ipsum</label</li>
   <li><label class="highlight"><input type="checkbox" id="55" class="filteritem">Lorem Ipsum</label</li>
</ul>
```

Every checkbox has an unique ID

I want to toggle the background-color of the label when it is checkt.

This is what i got but it does not work:

jQuery:

```
$(".filteritem").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
});
```

CSS:

```
.highlight {
    //change something
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HTML:

```
<ul class="checkboxlist">
   <li><label><input type="checkbox" id="1"> Lorem Ipsum</label></li>
   <li><label><input type="checkbox" id="223"> Lorem Ipsum</label></li>
   <li><label><input type="checkbox" id="32"> Lorem Ipsum</label></li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
$( '.checkboxlist' ).on( 'click', 'input:checkbox', function () {
   $( this ).parent().toggleClass( 'highlight', this.checked );
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/MGVHX/1/

Notice that I use **event delegation**, instead of binding the same handler to *every* check-box.

Comment: Yes, that's a nice solution. Simple but effective.

Answer (score 2):

You are currently trying to call `toggleClass` on the `input` element, not the `label`. You can use [`parent`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) to get the `label`:

```
$(".filteritem").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('highlight');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".filteritem").on('change', function(){
     $(this).closest('label').toggleClass('highlight');
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/xgCMf/)